# strongloop loopback android sdk extending installation class

Tags: strongloop

I am using the loopback android sdk example and  trying to extend Installation Class in android SDK to add more attribute to the installation . But when I add add a new attribute it gives me the following error.

```
11-16 20:51:33.207    4339-4339/com.google.android.gcm.demo.app E/GCM Demo﹕ Cannot save Installation
org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unprocessable Entity
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.sendResponseMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:235)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequest(AsyncHttpRequest.java:79)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.makeRequestWithRetries(AsyncHttpRequest.java:95)
        at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpRequest.run(AsyncHttpRequest.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

The way I am doing it is,

```
public class CustomInstallation extends LocalInstallation {


public static final java.lang.String DEVICE_IMEI= "imei";
private String imeiNumber;


public ProbeInstallation(Context applicationContext, RestAdapter loopbackAdapter) {
    super(applicationContext, loopbackAdapter);
}

public String getImeiNumber() {
    return imeiNumber;
}

public void setImeiNumber(String imeiNumber) {
    this.imeiNumber = imeiNumber;
}}
```

And in my MainActivity I am just using it as,

```
   final CustomInstallation installation =  new CustomInstallation(context, adapter);
```

Is this the way to do it or I am missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP error `422 Unprocessable Entity` is returned by LoopBack when the validation of the model instance failed. This typically happens when a required field (property) was not included in the request body.

Please extend your question and add the LDL definition of your `ProbeInstallation` model.

Also note that the current implementation of `LocalInstallation` does not fully support extending, since the `save` method uses always `/installations` URL and the URL cannot be configured. Of course, this can be easily improved, feel free to open a GitHub issue or perhaps even send a pull request.

*Disclaimer: I am the main developer of loopback-sdk-android*

Comment: Ok, I see. I will try to send a pull request. thanks.
What if in server I extend the Installation model, extend it and add an attribute ?
Also, why your LocalInstallation does not extend Model in your android app? Is it just ti show and example? since  .save method is available in the Model class and we can use it .

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good place to discuss this. Please post your questions to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/loopbackjs or open a GH issue.